# Implementation of tree-traversal: pre-order

Tags: haskell, tree-traversal

I have to implement a pre-order tree traversation: 
The result of (Knoten 'A'(Blatt 'B')(Blatt 'C')) have to be ['A','B','C']

This is my Code but there was a mistake I am not able to find:

```
data Baum a = Blatt a | Knoten a 
                           (Baum a)
                           (Baum a)

preorder (Blatt () ) = []
preorder (Knoten a l r) = [a] ++ preorder l ++ preorder r
```

Comment: `preorder (Blatt x) = [x]`

Comment: thank you, now it says something like: Equations for `preorder' have different numbers of Arguments, how can I avoid this?

Comment: No it doesn't. Not if you have the code you pasted above and replace the problematic base case.

Comment: on a side note - get in the habit of adding a type signature to your top level functions sthg like `preorder :: Baum a -> [a]` - note that your implementation right now does not use any ordering - so the signature might change to sthg. like `preorder :: (Ord a) => Baum a -> [a]`

Comment: thank you :)) Now i don´t get the right answer, I get something like: 'ABC', but I have to get: ['A','B','C']

Comment: `"ABC"` is the same as `['A','B','C']` as `type String = [Char]`.

Comment: you are right, I have to define it before when I want a [Char], am I right?

Comment: no you don't have to define that - it is already implemented like that. The only special about `String` is that when you `show` a `String` you get the usual representation of a `String` instead of the "listy" one you are looking for.

Comment: @Tikotakatok Try typing `['A', 'B', 'C']` into ghci (or your preferred interpreter). What does it print? Does this surprise you? Why or why not?

Comment: Also note that you cannot represent an empty tree using this definition. Typical tree definitions should be able to be empty, so generally this means you should rethink your type.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe, why would you need `Ord` to perform a preorder traversal? That seems very strange.

Comment: @dfeuer you are completely right.